# Syncronized layout in asyncTask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I have built a layout programmatically in this class: TableMainLayout.

Before viewing this layout download the data from an AsyncTask. When I finished downloading the layout I want you to always inside the AsyncTask is pre loaded the layout for the next view.

I need to find a way to synchronize this, otherwise I will part the intent when it has not finished loading the layout.

I explain better with the code:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        TableMainLayout layout = new TableMainLayout();
                    synchronized ( ???  ) {
                        Intent iData = new Intent(context, ActionBarTabs.class);
                        context.startActivity(iData);
                    }

    }
```

What should I put in place of the question marks?

Or have any other advice?
In short, I have to wait for that class is initialized before you go to make the intent.

thanks

Comment: What does TableMainLayout do ? What is the link with ActionBarTabs ? You should not start an activity from a thread that is not UI thread.

Comment: TableMainLayout create the layout for the next view. is a particular thing so I had to create it programmatically. The problem is that when there is too much data before you see a black screen and then when he's finished showing the view. So to avoid this I would load the first class TableMainLayout.

Comment: When new TableMainLayout() is finished, the layout is loaded, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    // Loading the layout
    TableMainLayout layout = new TableMainLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
    // The layout is loaded, starting the activity
    Intent iData = new Intent(context, ActionBarTabs.class);
    context.startActivity(iData);
}
```